# Changing Yes/No CSV Column to Numeric Data in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file with yes/no answers in one column.  I opened it in my R compiler and tried to run pairs() on it; however, I get an error message of "non-numeric argument to pairs."  I have attempted to change the yes/no responses to 0/1 values, but as.numeric() and as.factor() don't seem to do anything.  I have also tried changing the data type from character to numerical in the data editor window that appears when I use the fix() function.  That results in a column full of "NA".

How can I change the yes/no responses into something that will work with pairs() and with plot()?
I am fairly new to R and would much appreciate your help.

Comment: if `x <- c("yes","no","yes")`, then `+(x == "yes")` returns `c(1L,0L,1L)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logical` vectors can be cast fairly directly into numbers using a shortcut `+(.)`. For instance,

```r
x <- c("yes","no","yes")
(x == "yes")
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
+(x == "yes")
# [1] 1 0 1
```